# Favorites showing on all users, not the specific one a user favorites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch

Attempting to make a favorites button, then when clicked will only show favorites for a specific user not show all favorites for all users.  My OnClick is hitting my POST correctly, and on the backend when a user favorites a coffee shop it only shows against their profile not anyone else.  So I think its just the way im attempting to display this information to the user.  I am using React frontend/Rails backend and JWT for Auth.

My Controller

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorized, only:[:create]
    def index
        favorite = Favorite.find_by(params[:user_id])
        favorites = Favorite.all 
        render json: favorites
    end

    def show
        favorite = Favorite.find_by(params[:user_id])
        render json: favorite
    end
....
```

my onClick ...

```
....
 <button className="submit-fav" onClick={(e) => {this.handleAdd(e)}}>  ♥  </button>
...
```

my fetch to addToFav and show favs

```
addToFav = (cafe) => {
  console.log(cafe)
  fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites`,{
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `bearer ${localStorage.token}`
    },
      body: JSON.stringify( cafe )
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => alert(json.message)
  )}
...



 componentDidMount() {
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorites`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(favorites => this.setState({ favorites }))
    }
```

My Schema

```
 enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "coffee_shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.string "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "coffee_shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "reviewed_coffee"
    t.string "coffee_shop_name"
    t.string "user_username"
    t.integer "coffee_shop_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "city"
    t.string "img_url"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

Any more info needed let me know!

any advise appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saving favorite correctly and it's a joint table between user and cafe, then your index method is not correct.

First, you have two variables, `favorite` and `favorites`. The first one should actually be this, if you use `find_by`:

```
favorite = Favorite.find_by(user: params[:user_id])
```

The other line you have is the following:

```
favorites = Favorite.all
```

This queries all the favorites in your database, regardless of who favored them.
So if you want only the favorites that belong to one user you should do:

```
favorites = Favorite.where(user: params[:user_id])
```

Now this will only give you the records of the joint table when what you really want is the name and other information of the coffee shops.

So you will need to extend your query to the `coffee_shops` table and you can do so with a joins statement:

```
CoffeeShop.joins(:favorites).where(favorites: { user: params[:user_id] })
```

And this will give you a list of the CoffeeShops that were liked by the user, instead of just the records from the `favorites` table.

Comment: thanks for your help! Im still having issues with getting favorites to show correctly unless I do ```   favorites = Favorite.all ``` but goes back to my original issue of all users favorites showing not just the user who favorites them

Comment: Are you sure the favorites are saved correctly in the DB? Also, is `params[:user_id]` passing the right user id?

Comment: On the backend only the ID is getting saved under ```favorites``` for the coffee shop, but all the information like the name etc.. is getting saved under ```favorite_coffee_shops```

Comment: I updated my question with my Schema, im curious if its something to do with it?

Comment: I edited my answer, if you just do `Favorite.where(user: params[:user_id])` you will only get records from the `favorites` but you actually want the information from the `coffee_shops` table. Let me know if you have more questions!